# Is it possible to create a MySql DB with . in the name using ansible modules? How?

Tags: mysql, ansible

I am trying to create a DB with name like `example.com_db` in mysql DB using ansible.

here is my code

```
    mysql_db:
      login_user: root
      login_password: "{{ mysql_pass }}"
      name: "{{ domain_name }}_db"
      state: present
```

the error I am getting is this

> quote An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`com_db"`' at line 1')
> quote fatal: [vubuntu1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "error creating database: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'.`com_db\"`\' at line 1')"}

is there a way to create the Db using the module except shell module? I have tried using `community.mysql.mysql_db` module but it gives same result.

Comment: Think you'll need backticks around the whole name.

Comment: Thanks! that worked.

Comment: That's because it's an identifier. The `.`s unquoted denote children (db, table, column).